# How does retina.js not download the smaller images?

Tags: retina-display

I've been looking at retina.js which is a Javascript tool that looks for higher resolution versions of images and displays them to retina users. I've read that it doesn't download the smaller versions of the images for retina users, but I dont see how this could be the case.

If it uses Javascript to alter the image href, wont this be run after the browser has already fetched the original images linked in the HTML?

Comment: Who says it doesn't? At any rate, it's open-source, so you can [see for yourself](https://github.com/imulus/retinajs/blob/master/src/retina.js) how it works.